# why is reference initialization with 'operator ++' gives error

Tags: c++, reference

```
#include<iostream.h> 
int main()
{
    int m = 2;
    int &x = m++;
    cout<<m;
    return 0; 
}
```

this code should gives 
OUTPUT:
3

but this code gives error:
invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from a temporary of type 'int'.

Comment: What are trying to do with `int &x = m++;` ?

Comment: The result of `m++` is temporary object with lifetime restricted to this line. It cannot be assigned to reference - compiler message is quite clear. m++ keeps an old m value in temporary object, increments value of m, and returns temporary object with previous m value.

Comment: @FedericoReghenzani it should work as "int &x= m; m++;"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Post increment operator returns a temporary object with the value of `m` before increment.
Non `const` lvalue references can't be bound to temporary objects. Thus, the compiler rightfully complains.

Comment: @kkr_manit I missed the "non-const" word. This means that `int const &x = m++;` is legal ;)

Answer (score 6):

`m++` has to increase `m` (as a side effect), but evaluate to the original value. It does that by returning a temporary variable holding the value of `m` before increment.

An non-const l-value reference cannot bind to a temporary object.

You could write:

```
int &x = ++m;
```

This works because the pre–increment operator has to return the value after the increment, thus being able to evaluate to an l-value reference to `m`.

But I wouldn’t recommend that for clarity sake.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use post increment to assign references - it is a temporary object

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
int &x = m++;
```

you are assigning a temporary object (right side) to a reference(left side) which doesnt make any sense.

Instead,write:

> int &x = ++m;